# downloading sentinel-2 data with bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using the syntax below in google cloud platform to download sentinel-2 data  but I am getting error here STARTS_WITH(sensing_time, "2019")

#standardSQL
SELECT
base_url
FROM   `bigquery-public-data.cloud_storage_geo_index.sentinel_2_index`
WHERE (mgrs_tile="30NVL" OR mgrs_tile="30NVM" OR mgrs_tile="30NVN") AND  STARTS_WITH(sensing_time, "2019")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below instead

```
SELECT base_url 
FROM   `bigquery-public-data.cloud_storage_geo_index.sentinel_2_index` 
WHERE (mgrs_tile="30NVL" OR mgrs_tile="30NVM" OR mgrs_tile="30NVN") 
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sensing_time) = 2019
```

Here, instead of `STARTS_WITH(sensing_time, "2019")` you use `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sensing_time) = 2019`

Comment: This answered my question and I am very grateful to Mikhail Berlyant for his help

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.